# calling the descendant class of an element on jquery each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm using an each function on my jquery where in my parent is named as this inside my each function. I want to check the class `name` inside my class `list-item`. But my current code is showing this:

```
         $('.list-item').each(function(){
            if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
           $('.list-item').show();
       }
    });  


<li class="list-item">
   some data <span class="name">this data</span>
</li>
```

what should I change on my conditional statement for it to check the class name inside my `.list-item` instead of the entire `.list-item` content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your post correctly, you want to use `$.find()` to get the `.name` text. And you probably also want to show `$(this)` inside of the loop, instead of all `.list-item`'s.

```js
$('.list-item').each(function() {
  var nameText = $(this).find('.name').text();
  if (nameText.toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list-item">
   some data <span class="name">this data</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $('.list-item').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.name').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
             $(this).show();
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to to use .find()

```
   $('.list-item').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.name').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
       $('.list-item').show();
```